# Angular 5: Reactive Forms - Form group validation retrigger when form control updated

Tags: angular, custom-validators

I am using `Angular 5 Reactive forms`, and have setup a `form group` say `confirmEmail` with two `form controls` as `email` and `confirmEmail`. I have further added a `validator` to my `form group` and the `form controls` have `required` validations attached.

`My use case is`: I want to trigger the `custom validation` based on the value of the individual form controls and if the custom validator returns as `invalid`, mark the form controls as having errors.

`My issue is that`: Once the `form controls` are marked with errors, custom validator (which is on form group) does not trigger until I touch both of the form controls again and change the values for both of them.
I would ideally want to just update one of the fields (to match the other one) and be able to trigger the custom validation again.

Sample code:

```js
@Component({...})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  user: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.group({
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required]
      }, , { validator: validateEmail })
    });
  }

  const validateEmail = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
    const email = control.get('email');
    const confirmEmail = control.get('confirmEmail');

    if (email.value === confirmEmail.value) {
          return null;
     } else {
       this.setFieldAsInvalid(email);
       this.setFieldAsInvalid(confirmEmail);
       return { nomatch: true };
     }
  };

  private setFieldAsInvalid(field: AbstractControl) {
      field.setErrors({
        'invalid': true
      });
   }
}
```

Any suggestions to fix this or any other approach I should take.

Comment: can you attach the html code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing controls(email and confirmEmail) into invalid when they keep different values, **but** `return null` in ValidatorFun will only change current formcontrol's valid to true, **not all email and confirmEmail**.

---

**Solution1:** 
You can change email and confirmEmail **back to valid** via `field.setErrors(null)` when they keep same value.

```
if (email.value === confirmEmail.value) {
  // clear custom error for all related controls
  this.setFieldAsValid(email);
  this.setFieldAsValid(confirmEmail);
  return null;
} else {
  this.setFieldAsInvalid(email);
  this.setFieldAsInvalid(confirmEmail);
  return { nomatch: true };
}


private setFieldAsValid(field: AbstractControl) {
  field.setErrors(null);
}
```

see fixed **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b3sgb?file=app/app.component.ts)**.

---

**Solution2:** 
If you only care about error `nomatch`, you can track on formgroup `data` to see whether it has error of `nomatch` like below(*also included in above demo's template part*):

```
this.user.get('data').hasError('nomatch')
```

Mention that This way will leave the other formcontrol to be invalid.

Comment: When I was trying to do this, it so happened that because the fields got invalidated the first time, i had to change both of them inorder for the validate function to trigger; seems to be working here though with you demo. thanks for the ponters.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample form using the reactive approach in which I have used both built-in validator and custom validator.

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  forbiddenEmails = ['test@test.com'];

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.customEmailValidator.bind(this)])
  });

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.loginForm.get('email').value);
  }

  customEmailValidator(control: FormControl): {[params: string]: boolean}{
    console.log(this.forbiddenEmails.indexOf(control.value));
    if(this.forbiddenEmails.indexOf(control.value) === 0){
      return {'forbiddenEmail': true};
    }else{
       return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```
   <h3>Basic Form</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal"  [formGroup]='loginForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" 
                id="name" 
                class="form-control"
                formControlName='name' />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <span *ngIf='loginForm.get("name").invalid && loginForm.get("name").touched'>Pleas enter a valid name !!!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email"
                 id="email"
                 class="form-control"
                 formControlName="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <span *ngIf='loginForm.get("email").invalid && loginForm.get("email").touched'>Pleas enter a valid email !!!</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" 
        type="submit"
        [disabled]='!loginForm.valid'
        >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwahpa?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: sorry but your solution doesn't address my question